# How to deal with version conflict engine exception in elasticserach

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I used PHP Elasticsearch client and I always get exception like this

```
{
    "took": 17,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 3,
    "updated": 2,
    "deleted": 0,
    "batches": 1,
    "version_conflicts": 1,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
    },
    "throttled_millis": 0,
    "requests_per_second": -1.0,
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures": [{
        "index": "questions_statistics",
        "type": "_doc",
        "id": "IwSmq3kB2OehDv3R2YeP",
        "cause": {
            "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
            "reason": "[IwSmq3kB2OehDv3R2YeP]: version conflict, required seqNo [1927448], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [1927450] and primary term [1]",
            "index_uuid": "HW9XMxZtTLi2_Iv_Ryl01w",
            "shard": "0",
            "index": "questions_statistics"
        },
        "status": 409
    }]
}
```

It seems like version conflicts caused by optimistic locking. I think this type of exception should not be handled. Should I catch and write down the log? Or is there another way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are going to handle version conflict in your application, if you are using **Last Write Win** conflict resolution you can omit the version conflicts by providing manual versions in Elasticsearch, but if you want to be sure the document that you are writing to Elasticsearch already had newest fields value version conflict helps you to avoid updating a document that is updated before.
Regarding logging it is always good to keep all type of failing operations in your system.